# how to set value in noneditable editbox by using QTP

Tags: javascript, vbscript, qtp

in my web application some of screen completely deal with Js framework we are doing Automation with QTP plz help me on below issue,

Visualy weblist box if I click in that Edit box will activiate but it's completely Readonly+Non Editable if we click Dropdown Icon it will populate one window in their Tree type value(Ex:Class>>Branch>>Section) we need click Section and then press Set Button then selected values populating in the Edit box.
even though if i'm making Editbox property Readonly is false after entering the values in the edit box clicking submit button it's giving error Null value in that Edit box ?all these are developers completely written in Javascript Framework so is there way to directly entering values with out selecting Popup window values by using QTP(VBSCRIPT) or Javascript code?

Thanks

Comment: Please add some formatting to make your question more clear

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly understand your question but it seems to me that one of the options you're asking about is how to run JavaScript code from QTP. You can do this starting with QTP11 using `Page.RunScript` (or `Frame.RunScript`).